# VBA to call a python code opens shell but crashed

Tags: python, vba

I have a python program I am testing in `D:\Test\Hello_World.py` and the location of python executable is `D:\Software\Anaconda3\python.exe` , This opens the command prompt but does not run the file.

```
Sub ExecutePython()
Dim Objshell As Object
Dim Pythonexe, Pythonscript As String
Set Objshell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Pythonexe = """D:\Software\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
Pythonscript = "D:\Test\Hello_World.py"
Objshell.Run Pythonexe & Pythonscript
End Sub
```

Comment: Please either quote the `"\"` characters as `"\\"` or use raw strings `r"..."`. See if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which Location should I use the "\" at ? for the Exe file or the location of the script?

Comment: I tried doing for the python script location and it still didnt run

Comment: I tried with both files as well and it still didnt work

Comment: Sorry, need to go to work now ... I just see there is also no space between the executable and the script. Try `Objshell.Run Pythonexe & " " & Pythonscript`

Comment: still didnt work :(